# How can I save an enum String rawValue to Firebase's Cloud Firestore so the data is returned correctly as a String?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app which stores some basic user information for gymnast. As you can see from the screenshot below, it's a simple structure with Strings and 1 Bool. Everything looks fine on the Cloud Firestore console.

[image: Cloud Firestore screenshot]

When I fetch the data I use automatic type serialization to construct a series of `GymnastSummary`. This succeeds and showing a list of names and dates of birth work fine.

[image: GymnastSummary Object]

**My Issue**

When I try and access the `scheme` my app crashes. Looking at the object in Xcode the `scheme` and `schemeGender` are not as expected. The coincidence is that both of these values are selected from a list of enums and the `.rawValue` is saved to Cloud Firestore. When I first set it up I thought it was fine as the Cloud Firestore console was showing what I would expect. Is there something behind the scenes that I am missing when saving a `.rawValue` to Cloud Firestore.

[image]

I've included a screenshot of the two `enum`s. They're very basic.

[image: enums]

Comment: I think schemeGender passed "(" brackets instead of boy / girl

Comment: The first screenshot is from the Firebase console so it definitely passed “boy”, it’s when it’s read back it goes to “(“

Comment: In the future please don't post screenshots of your code, but post the code as text - and use the formatting options of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the structs are created with `Codable` just declare the struct member as enum type

```
var scheme : Scheme // why are all struct members optional?
```

and adopt `Codable` in the enum

```
enum Scheme : String, Codable, ...
```

The encoder / decoder does the conversion on your behalf.

---

Note:

Please post text, not images.

Comment: Thank you, that change has solved the issue. Apologises for the screenshots. I thought they displayed my issue clearly.

Comment: They do, but nobody who is willing to help is willing to retype a bunch of lines to test the code.